# how is reverse proxy done correctly with relative path

Tags: apache, redirect, proxy

I have the following set up to mask/redirect a url with port to a proxy 
ex.

```
VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName psweb1.example.com
ServerAlias psweb1.example.com
ProxyPass /demo1 http://psweb1.example.com:8002/
ProxyPassReverse /demo1 http://psweb1.example:8002/
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem with this set up is that the redirection does not capture any of the relative paths.

For example
psweb1.example.com:8002/main/login/login.jsp redirects to psweb1.example.com/demo1/main/login/login.jsp

Upon loggin in:
The redirection does not follow the strucutre of psweb1.example.com/demo1/*
Instead tries to go back to psweb1.example.com/*

How do I make sure of the proper mapping consistently stays with all the correct relative paths?
such as:

```
psweb1.example.com:8002/main > psweb1.example.com/demo1/main
psweb1.example.com:8002/main/login > psweb1.example.com/demo1/main/login
psweb1.example.com:8002/side/* > psweb1.example.com/demo1/side/*
```

etc etc.

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName psweb1.example.com
        ServerAlias psweb1.example.com

        ProxyPass /demo1/ http://psweb1.example.com:8002/
        ProxyHTMLURLMap http://psweb1.example.com:8002/ /demo1
        <Location /demo1/>
                ProxyPassReverse  http://psweb1.example.com:8002/
                SetOutputFilter proxy-html
                ProxyHTMLURLMap   /           /demo1/
                ProxyHTMLURLMap   /demo1        /demo1
                RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding
        </Location>

</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem here is actually *absolute* paths.  I suspect that relative paths are working correctly.  Consider:

Your browser fetches a page `psweb.example.com/demo1/main/` which includes a link of the form `<a href="login">...</a>`.  When you follow that link a browser, the browser will fetch `/demo1/main/login`, which is exactly what you want.

Now consider a link of the form `<a href="/main/login">...</a>`.  This is an *absolute* link.  In this case, your browser will fetch `psweb.example.com/main/login`.

You can't fix this with ProxyPass directives because it has nothing to do with the HTTP exchange between the browser and your server.  This is an issue with the HTML content being generated by your web application.  You typically have a few options:

1. Correctly configure the web application.  Many applications have a "base URL" setting of some sort designed exactly for this situation.
2. Fix the web application. Edit the code to either (a) always generate relative links or (b) always prepend the correct base URL.
3. Use an HTML filter, such as [mod_proxy_html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy_html.html), which is available as part of recent versions (2.4 and later, I think) of Apache, and as a third-party module for earlier versions.

Comment: Appreciate the response. I don't think I have exposure to 1 so 2 and 3 are the better options. 2 also requires the access to code base which I do not have. I have read some threads about #3 but my installation is shipped with 2.2 so mod_proxy_html is definitely not in the build. 

I am inclined to upgrading to 2.4 instead of updating with the compiled .so of this apache module, which sometimes acts wanky?